# Sending Multiple Rows of Data to One email address via Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Utilizing the code below, I am trying to send multiple lines of data to an email address all at once, but come across as one email per line. Right now I've found other examples on this site where they ALL will send (1) (1,2) (1,2,3) so they just keep cumulating.

```
function sendEmail() 
    {
   var ActiveSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
   var StartRow = 2;
   var RowRange = ActiveSheet.getLastRow() - StartRow + 1;
   var WholeRange = ActiveSheet.getRange(StartRow,1,RowRange,17);
   var AllValues = WholeRange.getValues();
   var message = "";
   for (var i=0;i<AllValues.length;i++) 
   {
     var CurrentRow = AllValues[i];
     var EmailSent = CurrentRow[16];
     if (EmailSent!="email_fwd")
     {
        message +=
            "<p><b>Body: </b>" + CurrentRow[1] + "</p>" +

            //"<p><b>Questions & Comments: </b>" + CurrentRow[15] + "</p><br><br>"
            "<p><b>XYZ ASSIGNEE:" + CurrentRow[2] + "</p>" +
            "<p><b>XYZ CATEGORY:rews;"+ "</p>" +
    "<p><b>XYZ TYPE:ua space;"+ "</p>" +
    "<p><b>XYZ ITEM:audit exception;"+ "</p>" ;
        var setRow = i + StartRow;
        ActiveSheet.getRange(setRow, 17).setValue("email_fwd");

        var SendTo = CurrentRow[4];
        var Subject = CurrentRow[0];
        MailApp.sendEmail({to: SendTo,cc: "",subject: Subject,htmlBody: message,});

    }
  }
}
```

I've got it displaying most of the way, but just the duplication of the same content in emails has got me stuck

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

```
function sendMultipleLinesOfDataToOneEmailAddressl() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var sr = 2;
  var vs = sh.getRange(sr, 1, sh.getLastRow() - sr + 1, sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  MailApp.sendEmail("Your email address", "Your Subject", JSON.stringify(vs).replace(/\],/g,']\n'));
}
```

With my test data the email looks like this:

[image]